# How to run h265 formatted video in flutter using vlc player package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

How to run h.265 codec formatted video in flutter, I have one h.265 video in locally.

I tried with locally, video not loading, not getting as expected, the documentation not much clear, so any one know how to implement h.256 video in flutter, that would be appreciated

Code example:

```
    import 'dart:io';
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart';
    
    class VlcPlaye extends StatefulWidget {
      const VlcPlaye({super.key});
    
      @override
      State<VlcPlaye> createState() => _VlcPlayeState();
    }
    
    class _VlcPlayeState extends State<VlcPlaye> {
late VlcPlayerController vlcPlayerController;
      bool _isloadong = false;
     
      @override
      void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        vlcPlayerController.dispose();
      }
    
      Future<File> getAssetVideoFile() async {
        ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/h265video.hevc');
        List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
    
        // Create a temporary file
        Directory tempDir = await Directory.systemTemp.createTemp();
        File tempFile = File('${tempDir.path}/h265video_temp.hevc');
    
        // Write the asset bytes to the temporary file
        await tempFile.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    
        return tempFile;
      }
    
      fomatVideo() async {
        try {
          setState(() {
            _isloadong = true;
          });
          File filePath = await getAssetVideoFile();
          vlcPlayerController = VlcPlayerController.asset(
            filePath.path,
            hwAcc: HwAcc.disabled,
            //autoInitialize: true,
            //addOnRendererEventListener
    
            autoPlay: true,
            options: VlcPlayerOptions(
                advanced: VlcAdvancedOptions([
                  // VlcAdvancedOptions.networkCaching(1000),
                  VlcAdvancedOptions.fileCaching(1000), 

                  // Use SurfaceView for video (try different options)
                ]),
                rtp: VlcRtpOptions([
                  VlcRtpOptions.rtpOverRtsp(true),
                ])),
          );
          setState(() {
            _isloadong = false;
          });
          vlcPlayerController.addListener(() {
            if (vlcPlayerController.value.isPlaying) {
              // Video has started playing
              print("playing kkkkk");
            }
          });
          // _vlcPlayerController.addOnRendererEventListener((p0, p1, p2) {
    
          // });
        } catch (e) {
          print("object1111$e");
        }
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        fomatVideo();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: const Text("Sample vlc player video"),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                _isloadong
                    ? SizedBox.shrink()
                    : VlcPlayer(
                        controller: vlcPlayerController,
                        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                        placeholder: const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        ),
                      ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      bool? value = await vlcPlayerController.isPlaying();
                      setState(() {
                        if (value == true) {
                          vlcPlayerController.pause();
                        } else {
                          vlcPlayerController.play();
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow)),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
           
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

I am not able run h265 formatted video,how to run h265 formatted video using vlc player package, any one please comment this one, I am stuck at this one, you replay would great helpful for me. Thank you